# how to retrieve data from vcenter the most quick way

Tags: powershell, vmware, vcenter

I am trying to collect performance data from vcenter for hosts. I've created this powershell script. It works but it takes a extremely long time to complete. Is there a better more efficient way to retrieve data from vcenters.

```
Connect-VIServer "vcenter.server.com" -User user123 -Password testpassword
$allvms = @()
$allhosts = @()
$hosts = Get-VMHost
$vms = Get-Vm

foreach($vmHost in $hosts){
  $hoststat = "" | Select HostName, MemMax, MemAvg, MemMin, CPUMax, CPUAvg, CPUMin
  $hoststat.HostName = $vmHost.name

  $statcpu = Get-Stat -Entity ($vmHost)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat cpu.usage.average
  $statmem = Get-Stat -Entity ($vmHost)-start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat mem.usage.average

  $cpu = $statcpu | Measure-Object -Property value -Average -Maximum -Minimum
  $mem = $statmem | Measure-Object -Property value -Average -Maximum -Minimum

  $hoststat.CPUMax = $cpu.Maximum
  $hoststat.CPUAvg = $cpu.Average
  $hoststat.CPUMin = $cpu.Minimum
  $hoststat.MemMax = $mem.Maximum
  $hoststat.MemAvg = $mem.Average
  $hoststat.MemMin = $mem.Minimum
  $allhosts += $hoststat
}
$allhosts | Select HostName, MemMax, MemAvg, MemMin, CPUMax, CPUAvg, CPUMin | Export-Csv "c:\output\Hosts.csv" -noTypeInformation
```

Comment: Have you considered using PowerShell jobs? You could create a background job for each VM host.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan, I even nailed down to one esx host within vcenter, it takes considerable time. Do you have an example jobs there you're referring to?

Comment: You can put all the code inside the `foreach` loop into a call to `Start-Job`. That way, you run a single background job for each VM host, instead of running all of the code synchronously. At the end of the script, you can use `Wait-Job` to wait for all the jobs to complete, and then aggregate the results together.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code, which moves the processing into a PowerShell background job:

```
Connect-VIServer "vcenter.server.com" -User user123 -Password testpassword
$allvms = @()
$allhosts = @()
$hosts = Get-VMHost;
$vms = Get-Vm;

# Define the code that will be executed as part of the background job
$Job = {
  $hoststat = @{};

  $statcpu = Get-Stat -Entity $args[0] -start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat cpu.usage.average;
  $statmem = Get-Stat -Entity $args[0] -start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Finish (Get-Date)-MaxSamples 10 -stat mem.usage.average;

  $cpu = $statcpu | Measure-Object -Property value -Average -Maximum -Minimum;
  $mem = $statmem | Measure-Object -Property value -Average -Maximum -Minimum;

  $hoststat.HostName = $args[0];
  $hoststat.CPUMax = $cpu.Maximum;
  $hoststat.CPUAvg = $cpu.Average;
  $hoststat.CPUMin = $cpu.Minimum;
  $hoststat.MemMax = $mem.Maximum;
  $hoststat.MemAvg = $mem.Average;
  $hoststat.MemMin = $mem.Minimum;

  return $hoststat;
}

$JobList = @();
foreach($vmHost in $hosts){
    $JobList += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Job -Name $vmHost.Name -ArgumentList $vmHost.Name;
}

Wait-Job -Job $JobList;
$JobList | % { $allhosts += Receive-Job -Job $PSItem; };
$allhosts | Select HostName, MemMax, MemAvg, MemMin, CPUMax, CPUAvg, CPUMin | Export-Csv "c:\output\Hosts.csv" -noTypeInformation
```

Comment: I just run this script as any other ps1?

Comment: although this is great, ran out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could collect multiple metrics from multiple host entities with a single get-stat call, as in,

```
get-stat -Entity $hosts -MaxSamples 10 -Stat "cpu.usage.average","mem.usage.average"
```

and then use `Group-Object` to parse the results. LucD's posts [here](http://www.lucd.info/2010/01/24/powercli-vsphere-statistics-part-4-grouping/) might be helpful.

I wonder if you need `$vms = Get-Vm` because the code you posted does not refer back to that.

Your PS session should be on the same LAN with the vcenter db. See also [kb.vmware.com/kb/2007388](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2007388).

Comment: get-stat command is taking a very long time. Do you know of any other way to get perfromance data from vcenters the quick way?

Comment: Not offhand, but an API might not help if queries to the vcenter db are performing poorly. See updated answer.

Comment: creating powershell script to pull data from vcenters take a very long time, I haven't seen it completed sucessfully so far. I am curious is there any other way?